# sqlite check if provided data exist then alert exist else alert doesnot

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

Am trying to check in the select query if the provided data in the where cause exist then alert the data exist else alert data dose not exist but am not getting how to achieve that.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaikasifpasha3/chsgf50t/13/)

```
var db = openDatabase("demo", "1.0", "demo", 200000);

            db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (Slno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, column1 TEXT UNIQUE, column2 TEXT UNIQUE, column3 TEXT UNIQUE, column4 TEXT UNIQUE, column5 TEXT UNIQUE)");
        },errorHandler);

db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test (column1, column2 ,column3, column4,column5) VALUES ('insert1','insert2','insert3','insert4','insert5');");
        },errorHandler);
```

Select Query

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM test where column1='insert1'");
        },errorHandler,successHandler);


function errorHandler(error) {
    alert("Error : " + error.message);
}

function successHandler  (transaction, resultSet) {
            alert(resultSet.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are receiving:-

```
Error : could not execute statement due to a constaint failure (19 UNIQUE constraint failed: test.column5)
```

because the browser is remembering the previous insert and the columns are unique.

and you have a slight formatting issue around your select transaction, try changing it to:-

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM test where column1='insert1'", [], successHandler, errorHandler);
},errorHandler);
```

complete answer:-

```
var db = openDatabase("demo", "1.0", "demo", 200000);

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (Slno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, column1 TEXT UNIQUE, column2 TEXT UNIQUE, column3 TEXT UNIQUE, column4 TEXT UNIQUE, column5 TEXT UNIQUE)");
},errorHandler);

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM test where column1='insert1'", [], successHandler, errorHandler);
},errorHandler);

function errorHandler(error) {
    alert("Error : " + error.message);
}

function successHandler  (transaction, resultSet) {
    alert(resultSet.rows.length);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chsgf50t/14/)